# How to sort JSON data by same values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data that looks something like this:

```js
{
"items":[
{"name":"Dondasch",
"tier":"Rare"
},
{"name":"Elight",
"tier":"Rare"
},
{"name":"Krak",
"tier":"Unique"
}
]
}
```

and I'm looking for a way to sort them by the "Tier: ???". I want to group all "items" that have the same value together, preferably in a way I define (As in, I can choose if the ones with "rare" or "unique" come first, rather than it being alphabetical. After I've sorted them, I need to be able to perform this code on them:

```js
data.items.forEach(wynnitem => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      $(h1).hide();
      h1.textContent = wynnitem.name;
      if (wynnitem.tier == "Unique") {
        h1.setAttribute('class', 'unique');
      } else if (wynnitem.tier == "Rare") {
        h1.setAttribute('class', 'rare');
      } else if (wynnitem.tier == "Legendary") {
        h1.setAttribute('class', 'legendary');
      } else if (wynnitem.tier == "Mythic") {
        h1.setAttribute('class', 'mythic');
      }
      $(h1).fadeIn(1000);
}):
```

Any other questions I've found just give a way to sort them alphabetically, not by a certain value.

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'",`

Comment: Instead of doing all those `if...else if...`, can't you just do  `h1.className = wynnitem.tier.toLowerCase();`? Also your line `$(h1).hide();` can safely be deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

you can apply `Array.prototype.sort` method to items and give it a compareFn

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.tier < b.tier) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.tier > b.tier) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would only need to define a ranking/priority table and sort by this criteria :

```
const orderRanks = {
  unique: 2,
  rare: 4,
  legendary: 42,
  mythic: 420
};

const items = /*your items array*/;
items.sort((lhsItem, rhsItem) => {
  const lhs = lhsItem.tier.toLowerCase();
  const rhs = rhsItem.tier.toLowerCase();
  return orderRanks[lhs] - orderRanks[rhs];
  /*
  == -> 0
  lhs < rhs -> negative
  lhs > rhs -> positive

  this works because it is simple numbers (not NaN nor limits)
  */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  var list = {
    "items":[
    {"name":"Dondasch",
    "tier":"Rare"
    },
    {"name":"Elight",
    "tier":"Rare"
    },
    {"name":"Krak",
    "tier":"Unique"
    }
    ]
    }
```

And then sort the data using

```
list.items.sort(function(a, b) { return a["tier"]-b["tier"]} || a["name"] - b["name"]);
```